# How do I find the row value when using append in the pyqt q standard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)
        self.list1 = [['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1','b2','b3'], ['c1','c2','c3']]
        self.list2 = [['d1','d2','d3'], ['e1','e2','e3'], ['f1','f2','f3']]
        self.table1()
        self.table2()
        self.layout()

    def table1(self):
        self.table1_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.table1_view = QTableView()
        self.table1_view.setEditTriggers(QTableView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.table1_view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.table1_view.doubleClicked.connect(self.table1_double)
        for row in range(len(self.list1)):
            for column in range(len(self.list1)):
                table = QStandardItem(str(self.list1[row][column]))
                self.table1_model.setItem(row, column, table)
                table.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table1_view.setModel(self.table1_model)

    def table1_double(self):
        index = self.table1_view.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()
        self.modelRow = self.get_items_by_row(index, self.table1_model)
        self.table2_model.appendRow([QStandardItem(text) for text in self.modelRow])
        self.qSpinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.qSpinbox.setRange(0, 1000)
        self.qSpinbox.setValue(0)
        self.qSpinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.table2_Spinbox)
        ix = self.table2_model.index(self.table2_model.rowCount() - 1, 2)
        self.table2_view.setIndexWidget(ix, self.qSpinbox)

    def table2_Spinbox(self, s):
        index = self.table1_view.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()
        print(index, s)

    def get_items_by_row(self, row, model):
        return [model.data(model.index(row, col)) for col in range(model.columnCount())]

    def table2(self):
        self.table2_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.table2_view = QTableView()
        self.table2_view.setEditTriggers(QTableView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.table2_view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.table2_view.setModel(self.table2_model)
        self.table2_button = QPushButton('test button')
        self.table2_button.clicked.connect(self.t2button)

    def t2button(self):
        self.table2_model.clear()
        for row in range(len(self.list2)):
            for column in range(len(self.list2)):
                table = QStandardItem(str(self.list2[row][column]))
                self.table2_model.setItem(row, column, table)
                table.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                spinbox = QSpinBox()
                spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.talbe2_Spinbox2)
                i = self.table2_view.model().index(row, 2)
                self.table2_view.setIndexWidget(i, spinbox)
                self.modelRow = self.get_items_by_row(row, self.table2_model)
                self.table2_model.item(row, column).setBackground(QColor('lightblue'))

    def talbe2_Spinbox2(self,s):
        index = self.table2_view.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()
        print(index, s)

    def layout(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table1_view)
        layout.addWidget(self.table2_view)
        layout.addWidget(self.table2_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the code above, there are two view screens, and if you double-click on the first view screen, the selected value is entered in the second view screen. I am curious to see how the spinbox value added with can represent a normal value.

Let me explain with an example.

Pressing the test button
There are 3 values.

The value of ʻindex' is `0 value` `1 value` `2 values` (when append is added)
The value of ʻindex' should be 4, but it starts from 0 or the value comes out jumbled. And the spin box value is not applied. I am curious to know which part needs to be corrected.

Comment: I am not following the problem, what index should be 4? what you expect as the output?

Comment: [1]. Press the test button and 3 values ​​appear in the second view
[2]. Double-click the value in the first view and paste it in the second view.
[3]. This will create a total of 4 values ​​(3 test buttons + 1 first view).
[4]. When the 4th spin box is rotated, the index value is 4 and the spin box value is maintained. (If you add 2 in the first view, the index value should be 4, 5, and the spin box value should be stored respectively. Do it.

Comment: Ok I think your problem is in function `table2_Spinbox`, where you are printing your output. am I right? if that is the case I think changing it into `index = self.table2_view.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()` can solve the issue. also in programming languages, indices are started from zero in arrays and tables,... but you can always change next line from `print(index, s)` to `print(index+1, s)`